# Edit method in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am building an e-store web app using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. I am trying to do CRUD operations with the help of some tutorial, everything went smoothly, but when I try to edit a product, it makes a copy of that edited item, instead of just replacing it.

Also, it asks me to upload a new image even though I want to set it not to ask for a new one, and there is a default (`noimage.png`) set if there is no image uploaded. Here is the edit method, please tell me where am going wrong.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, Product product)
{
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(_context.Category.OrderBy(x => x.Sorting), 
                                        "Id", "Name", product.CategoryId);

    // if (ModelState.IsValid)
    // {

    product.Slug = product.Name.ToLower().Replace(" ", "-");

    var slug = await _context.Product
                             .Where(x => x.Id != id)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Slug == product.Slug);

    if (slug != null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The product already exists.");
        return View(product);
    }

    // Not mandatory to upload an image when editing
    if (product.ImageUpload != null)
    {
        string uploadsDir = Path.Combine(webHost.WebRootPath, "media/products");

        // If the image is not noimage.png then remove the existing image and upload a new one
        if (!string.Equals(product.Image, "noimage.png"))
        {
            string oldImagePath = Path.Combine(uploadsDir, product.Image);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(oldImagePath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(oldImagePath);
            }
        }

        // Upload new image
        string imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + product.ImageUpload.FileName;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsDir, imageName);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

        await product.ImageUpload.CopyToAsync(fs);

        fs.Close();

        product.Image = imageName;
    }

    _context.Update(product);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    TempData["Success"] = "The product has been edited!";

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    // }

    // return View(product);
}
```

Product class

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minimum length 2")]

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Slug { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal (18,2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You must choose a category")] //specific validation for category
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required, MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minimum length 4")]
        public string? Description { get; set; }

        public string? Image { get; set; }

        //To make the connection
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public virtual Category? Category { get; set; }

        [NotMapped] //to not show in the DB
        [ImageExtention]
        public IFormFile? ImageUpload { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit view

```
@model Product

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Product";
}

<h1>Edit Product</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <form asp-action="Edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            @*<input type="hidden" asp-for="Image" />*@

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="@ViewBag.CategoryId" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">Choose a category</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label">Current Image</label>
                <img src="~/media/products/@Model.Image" width="200" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label">New Product Image</label>
                <input asp-for="ImageUpload" class="form-control" />
                <img src="" id="imgpreview" class="pt-2" alt="" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ImageUpload" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }

    <script>
        $("#ImageUpload").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal executable demo for use to test your code, It's difficult to find the error just base on the code you provided.

Comment: what else do u need me to provide u, i edite my code and add few classes, hope it helps?

Comment: From your question, You do not submit any Product's Id, SO database will not know which record you want to update, I also don't understand why you return `The product already exists.` error message when `slug != null`, This is your edit method right? User update Only the data exists in db.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make `Id` as `Primary Key` in Product

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //ommitted
}
```

2. You are not posting `Id` to `Edit` Method while `Edit` button clicked. So every time It is sending value of `Id` as `0`. `EntityFramework` is considering it as new object.

Please add below code to `cshtml` view inside form. It will send correct value of existing product Id.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
```